# How to Access variable from different method in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I access variables on page_load and use it on ddlApp_SelectedIndexChanged method in c#? 
thank you

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlRole.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    string ddl = ddlApp.Value.ToString();
    string ddlRoleDs;
    string ddlMenuDs;
    string GvDs;

    if (ddl == "ATTD")
    {
        ddlRoleDs = "ddlAttdDs";
        ddlMenuDs = "ddlMenuAttdDs";
        GvDs = "AttdMenuAssignmentDs";                
    }
    else if (ddl == "TRVL")
    {
        ddlRoleDs = "ddlTrvldDs";
        ddlMenuDs = "ddlMenuTrvlDs";
        GvDs = "TrvlMenuAssignmentDs";                
    }

}
```

the variable: ddlRoleDs, GvDs and ddMenuDs

```
protected void ddlApp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    ddlRole.DataSourceID = ddlRoleDs;
    MenuAssignmentGv.DataSourceID = GvDs;
    ddlMenu.DataSourceID = ddlMenuDs;
}
```

Comment: If the two methods are in the same class you can use global variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use private global members in your class. This way they can only be accessed from within the class. The code below shows you exactly how to declare and use them

```
private string ddlRoleDs;
private string GvDs;
private string ddMenuDs;

private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // don't declare them here, but you can use them here
    ddlRoleDs = "test value";
    ....
}
```

After the values were set in the Page_load method, they can be used in your other method

```
protected void ddlApp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    ddlRole.DataSourceID = ddlRoleDs;
    MenuAssignmentGv.DataSourceID = GvDs;
    ddlMenu.DataSourceID = ddlMenuDs;
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works now. but seem it doesn't work in Gridview event handler. i use the variable to set data source of a ComboBox datasourceID in a gridview.

Comment: that's another question, you can find the answer to that here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5976511/6198927. Don't forget to mark your question as answered

Comment: thank you. how to mark question as answered? sorry i still new in stackoverflow